# Laravel query, most sold product

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to find the most sold product today in laravel:

order:id, id_client
order_items: id_order, id_product, quantity, price

```
 $max=Order::join('orders_item','orders.id', '=','orders_item.id_order')

            ->whereDate('orders.created_at','=', date('Y-m-d'))
            ->select('id_product')
            ->groupBy('id_order')
            ->max('quantity');

$most_sold_product_today=Order::join('orders_item','orders.id', '=','orders_item.id_order')

          ->where('orders_item.quantity','=',$max)
            ->whereDate('orders.created_at','=', date('Y-m-d'))
            ->get();
```

But I don't get 5 most products, but I know that the query isn't correct. Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $max=DB::table('orders_item')
        ->join('orders','orders.id', '=','orders_item.id_order')
        ->select('orders_item.id_product')
        ->whereDate('orders.created_at','=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->groupBy('orders_item.id_order')
        ->max('orders_item.quantity');

 $most_sold_product_today=Order::
        join('orders_item','orders.id', '=','orders_item.id_order')
        ->where('orders_item.quantity','=',$max)
        ->whereDate('orders.created_at','=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$buyProductLists = Order::select('product_id',DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->groupBy('product_id')
            ->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
            ->get();


$mostSellingProduct = Product::whereIn('id', $buyProductLists->pluck('product_id'))
->get();

return ProductResource::collection($mostSellingProduct);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Order::whereDate('date','<',date('Y-m-d'))->select('product_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))->groupBy('product_id')->orderBy('count', 'DESC')->limit(5)->get();
```

It will gives you the top 5 selling products ID and their sell count.